# How to use an 'AND query to ensure 2 values are met within a 'group by'

Tags: mysql

I have a database that is grouped by start times and the position ranked by Price (Horse Racing data). I want to pull the top 3 and see if the prices meets the following:

- row 1 is less than 2.0
- row 2 is less than 7
- row 3 is less than 11

I have tried the following :

```
SELECT * 
FROM BFHorsePrice 
WHERE DATE(`ENTRY`) = CURDATE() 
AND (`row`= 1 AND `Lay` < '2') 
AND (`row`= 2 AND `Lay`< '7')
AND (`row`= 3 AND `Lay`< '11') 
GROUP BY `timeandcourse
```

The followng would be a selection
[image]

So group by timeandcourse.

If (row = 1 and Lay < 2) and (row = 2 and Lay < 7) and (row = 2 and Lay < 11) pull that group

Comment: Feels like you are asking for `HAVING` here.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: SELECT * FROM BFHorsePrice WHERE DATE(`ENTRY`) = CURDATE()  GROUP BY `timeandcourse` 
HAVING (`row` = '1' AND Lay < '2') 
AND(`row` = '2' AND Lay < '99') 

I tried this which should have pulled something but i get 0 results

Comment: Row cant be 1, 2 and 3 at the same time by the way i now just noticed you need to to use OR between most likely.. if that does not help as mine first comment about making a example

Comment: What do you expect  the output should look like?

Comment: Like AND(`row`= 1 AND `Lay` < '2') OR (`row`= 2 AND `Lay`< '7')

Comment: So if I group by timeandcourse I need row 1 to be under 2.0 on lay / row 2 to be under 7 to lay and row 3 to be under 11 to lay.

If all those match pull back result

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 columns or more in `GROUP BY` like:

```
GROUP BY timeandcourse, my_second_column, my_third_column
```

[source](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Select more or less as you were, only ORing the table row conditions, since WHERE is only able to check one row at a time, but then ensure you have found all the rows you wanted:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BFHorsePrice 
WHERE DATE(`ENTRY`) = CURDATE() 
AND (
    (`row`= 1 AND `Lay` < '2') 
    OR (`row`= 2 AND `Lay`< '7')
    OR (`row`= 3 AND `Lay`< '11') 
)
GROUP BY `timeandcourse`
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(row order by row) = '1,2,3';
```

Comment: it didnt pull the data sadly - i have update the question

Comment: add output of `show create table BFHorsePrice` and insert statements for your sample data to the question and I can see what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT * BFHorsePrice  
WHERE `timeandcourse` IN
(
    SELECT `timeandcourse` FROM BFHorsePrice 
    WHERE DATE(`ENTRY`) = CURDATE() 
    AND ((`row`= 1 AND `Lay` < '2') 
    OR (`row`= 2 AND `Lay`< '7')
    OR (`row`= 3 AND `Lay`< '11'))
)
```